# *ngFor is undefined in custom template and defined / works in ul > li

Tags: angular, ngfor

I believe this is not a duplicate as I did not find similar case after spending hours.

I just started learning Angular.

I do not get why *ngFor is undefined in custom template and defined / works in ul > li.

Code below produces following result:

```
companions-list works!

I am in companion-item.component.html
companion is null
I am in companion-item.component.html
companion is null
I am in companion-item.component.html
companion is null

Companion from UL - LI - name: Alex; rating: 8.4

Companion from UL - LI - name: Ben; rating: 8.2

Companion from UL - LI - name: Charlie; rating: 8.6
```

companions-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-companions-list',
  templateUrl: './companions-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companions-list.component.css']
})
export class CompanionsListComponent implements OnInit {

  companions = [
    {name: 'Alex', rating: 8.4},
    {name: 'Ben', rating: 8.2},
    {name: 'Charlie', rating: 8.6}
  ];

  constructor() { }    
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

companions-list.component.html

```
<div>
  companions-list works!

  <div *ngIf="companions">
    <app-companion-item *ngFor="let companion of companions"></app-companion-item>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let companion of companions">
        <div class="boxed">
        Companion from UL - LI - name: {{ companion.name }}; rating: {{ companion.rating }}
        </div>
        <br/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

companion-item.component.html:

```
<div class="boxed">
  I am in    companion-item.component.html
  <div *ngIf="companion == null">companion is null</div>
  <div *ngIf="companion">
    companion: name: {{ companion.name }}; rating: {{ companion.rating }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing anything? Thank you

Comment: You never pass any input to your app-companion-item component. Where could it get the companion from then? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: You are missing an `@Input` property in your `companion-item.component`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an input to the component (`[companion]="companion"`)

`<app-companion-item *ngFor="let companion of companions" [companion]="companion"></app-companion-item>`

and use  `@Input('companion') companion: any;` In your app-companion-item class (tho change any for another type, make an interface if possible).

See these docs [Angular Component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)